# deploying spring scheduler jar in Weblogic server

Tags: weblogic

We have a jar which contains the main method with spring scheduler implementation which is invoked every 1 min.

Is it possible to deploy this jar in weblogic server (12c) and server should be able to kick this jar as soon as it's deployed.

Comment: which machine did you use? windows or linux?

Comment: you cannot run a jar's main method via weblogic deployment